# How and when is the libc shared object library created?

Tags: c, compilation, cross-compiling, libc

I'm searching for gadgets for return oriented programming in the libc library. The conundrum that I've run into is that the offset (or relative address) of similar gadgets vary in the libraries (same version, 2.15) on two different systems - mine and a colleague's.

My system specifications:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.10
Processor: Intel i5 M480
Virtual OS: Yes
Libc version: 2.15
```

Colleague's system's specifications:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo T6670
Virtual OS: No
Libc version: 2.15
```

The following gadget

```
pop ecx ; pop eax ;;
```

has two different relative addresses. On mine the address is `0xf2c60` and on my colleague's it is `0xf2d21`.

However this gadget

```
mov [eax] ecx ;
```

has the same relative address on both systems - `0x2d71f`.

I have two questions.

1. Is libc compiled while the OS is being installed and so the two libraries vary a little because the systems they were compiled on are different? Or are they two different versions of libc (I'm not ruling this out because the versions of Ubuntu are different - sorry if I sound ignorant) but GCC does not bother reflecting the minor changes in the version code?
2. I've read that the relative address of a gadget can be found by going through the source and that the binary isn't required. How would one accomplish this? Please do not point to the "Hacking Blind" paper. I've already read it and they don't show a way to accomplish this, they instead show a way to guess the gadgets one by one. This will not be viable for demonstrations. Or this there a tool I can use to cross-compile libc if the answer to the first question is indeed system specification differences?

Comment: Don't ask several questions in one. Most significant for the actual address where you find a particular line of code is the compiler. From version to version they do different optimizations, so code positions shift easily. Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 certainly use different versions of gcc to produce their packages.

Comment: @JensGustedt - Thanks for confirming that. Any idea how I can make finding gadgets a version agnostic process using the source?